# Ошибка: string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Первая строка входного файла содержит S (принятое сообщение, состоящее из символов 1 и 0). Вторая строка содержит число N (количество следующих сообщений). Следующие N строк содержат эти сообщения. Длины всех сообщений равны.

В первую строку выходного файла нужно вывести число K (количество сообщений, которые отличаются от принятого сообщения S минимальным количеством позиций). Во вторую строку выведите в порядке возрастания К чисел — номера этих сообщений (нумерация начинается с 1).

Пример:

Принимаем:

010101

3

110011

011001

000111

Выводим:

2

2 3

Мой код:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s; // принятое сообщение
    int n; // количество следующих сообщений
    string m; // следующие сообщения
    int min; // мин. кол-во отличных позиций
    int k; // кол-во сообщений, которые отличаются от s мин. кол-вом позиций
    int d[100]; // их номера

    ifstream fin ("INPUT.TXT");

    getline(fin, s); // считываем принятое сообщение
    fin >> n; // считываем n

    min = s.length(); // min присваиваем длину строки

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        getline(fin, m); // считываем сообщение

        int diff = 0; // количество отличий = 0
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
            if (s[j] != m[j]) diff++; // если отличаются, то увеличиваем счетчик

        if (diff < min) // если эта строка отличается на меньшее кол-во позиций
        {
            min = diff; // min присваиваем это кол-во отличных позиций
            k = 1; // k присваиваем 1
            d[k - 1] = i; // вносим номер в массив
        }

        else if (diff == min) // если нашлось такое же кол-во позиций
        {
            k++; // увеливаем k
            d[k - 1] = i; // вносим номер в массив
        }
        m = "";
    }

    fin.close();
    ofstream fout ("OUTPUT.TXT");

    fout << k << endl; // выводим количество сообщений
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        fout << d[i] << " "; // и их номера

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Что мне нужно исправить? Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Поменяйте `getline(fin, m);` на `fin >> m;` или удалите пустые строки в вводе, т.к. getline читает до конца строки и считывает пустые строки.

Comment: Поменяла. Не помогло

Comment: Используйте отладку

Comment: В вашем предыдущем вопросе на эту же тему вам было четко указано на очевидные проблемы в вашем коде. В точности эти же самые проблемы во всей красе присутствуют и в этом варианте кода. Из-за этих же самых проблем падает и эта версия кода. Зачем вы задаете тут эти вопросы, если ответы на них вы просто отмечаете и игнорируете?